# Driver/Resolution Problem Makes MATE 16.04 Useless

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution, mate

Just installed ubuntu mate 16.04 64-bit.

Have screen resolution set as 1600x1200, which produces temporarily workable but distorted screen images.

Native resolution is 1920x1080, but selecting that results in very badly distorted screen image.

Cannot resolve with proprietary driver for intel integrated chipset.  Had no issues with any previous version or flavor of ubuntu.  Need help.

Comment: why do you think it is Mate problem and not Ubuntu-in-general problem for new release? Can you boot (e.g. from USB stick) into "normal" Ubuntu and have expected behaviour without same problem?

I ask because Mate does not provide driver-level infrastructure, they use host system, and while some kinks might slip in in configuration, most probably it is lower layer which has problem.

Comment: I think it is an ubuntu problem -- they messed up on some of their settings or did not include all the drivers.  I only said MATE so people would know I was using that flavor.  In fact, I had the same problem with all flavors and the main program.  I guess Iĺl just use Debian until they fix it -- spent hours on it myself, to no avail.

Comment: I requested change of title, just to reflect your own words above - it is Ubuntu problem, not Mate in first place. mentions of mate everywhere else are left as-is, we need to keep facts cold.

Comment: This is clearly a bug, you'd better report it in launchpad so that developers get aware of it.

The best way to report this bug is by running this command from the machine where you experience this problem:


    `ubuntu-bug xorg`


Alternatively, you can file a bug manually here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+filebug

Comment: Thanks, mardy and silpol.  I don't yet have a solution, but filed a bug report as best I could (in light of the fact that I am not able to do it from within Ubuntu at this time).  Link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1599952  That's all I can do to get the developers' attention, I think.